# Short simple sentence vs long complicated sentence

Tags: style

I learned here that in general being concise is considered good style. I wrote the short, simple bold sentence.

> Disagreements related to which airline, hotel, or restaurant to use
> could add fun-killing tension to our trip. However, a tensionless trip
> during which no one challenges choices could, just as easily, be a
> boring one. **The same can be true of other aspects of our lives.**

However, the freelancer I hired who is a native speaker turned it into a complicated, long sentence. Do you think the freelancers' version is an improvement?

> Disagreements related to which airline, hotel, or restaurant to use
> could add fun-killing tension to our trip. However, I think a
> tensionless trip during which no one challenges choices could, just as
> easily, be a boring one. **What applies to that trip, a small part of
> one’s life, also applies to the greater part of our lives.**

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic, but FWIW I prefer your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that being concise is typically preferred. When learning a new language, it might be challenging to speak/write correctly without being too formal. Here is another option:

> Disagreeing on which airline, hotel, or restaurant to choose can add
> stress to any trip. However, a trip with no challenges could be
> boring. The same is true in life. Stressful moments and moments of
> ease are all a part of life.